# Extract specific parts of a matlab/ octave symbolic expression?

Tags: matlab, octave, symbolic-math

How does one extract specific parts of an expression in Matlab/ Octave symbolic package?  In XCAS, one can use indexing expressions, but I can't find anything similar in Octave/ Matlab.

For instance, with `X = C*L*s**2 + C*R*s + 1`, is there a way to get `C*R*s` by  `X(2)` or the like?

It would be nice to do this with factors too.  `X = (alpha + s)*(beta**2 + s**2)*(C*R*s + 1)`, and have `X(2)` give `(beta**2 + s**2)`.

Thanks!

Comment: `children` does this but the order in which you write the expressions will not be maintained.

Comment: That's the answer, if you post it I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`children` ([*MATLAB doc*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/children.html), [*Octave doc*](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/@sym/children.html)) does this but the order in which you write the expressions will not necessarily be the same. The order is also different in MATLAB and Octave.

### Expanded Expression:

```
syms R L C s;
X1 = C*L*s^2 + C*R*s + 1;
partsX1 = children(X1);
```

**In MATLAB:**

```
>> X1
X1 =
C*L*s^2 + C*R*s + 1

>> partsX1
partsX1 =
[ C*R*s, C*L*s^2, 1]
```

**In Octave:**

```
octave:1> X1
X1 = (sym)

      2            
  C⋅L⋅s  + C⋅R⋅s + 1

octave:2> partsX1
partsX1 = (sym 1×3 matrix)

  ⎡       2      ⎤
  ⎣1  C⋅L⋅s   C⋅R⋅s⎦
```

---

### Factorised Expression:

```
syms R C a beta s;   %alpha is also a MATLAB function so don't shadow it with your variable
X2 = (a + s) * (beta^2 + s^2) * (C*R*s + 1);
partsX2 = children(X2);
```

**In MATLAB:**

```
>> X2
X2 =
(a + s)*(C*R*s + 1)*(beta^2 + s^2)

>> partsX2
partsX2 =
[ a + s, C*R*s + 1, beta^2 + s^2]
```

**In Octave:**

```
octave:3> X2
X2 = (sym)

          ⎛ 2    2⎞            
  (a + s)⋅⎝β  + s ⎠⋅(C⋅R⋅s + 1)

octave:4> partsX2
partsX2 = (sym 1×3 matrix)

  ⎡                    2   2⎤
  ⎣C⋅R⋅s + 1   a + s   β + s ⎦
```